# How to install pulse during RHEL 5.9 install

Tags: redhat, load-balancing, high-availability

I am desperately trying to install pulse on a rhel5.9 machine.

I have tried googling all over but all I get are instruction on how to configure pulse/piranha on an already installed box.

I have seen that rhel 6.x allows a user to chose load balancing/ High availability repositories thus allowing the user to install pulse service.

Kindly assist

Comment: Are you trying to automate the install on new boxes or are you having issues applying pulse to rhel5.9?

Comment: @Antitribu applying pulse to rhel5.9 while installing rhel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the RHEL 5 kickstart, enable the channel that the packages are in with a `repo --name=... --baseurl=...` line, then either include the package in the `%packages` section or (more to my preference) do a `yum -y install` in %post.